# How to get the sorting fields and order from a Query object in AppMaker?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-app-maker

In their examples there's something like this:

```
var query = app.models.Person.newQuery();
query.sorting.Name._ascending();
```

How can I extract the column and order from this?

I tried `console.log(Object.keys(query.sorting));` but it doesn't work.

Comment: Are you wanting a list essentially that gives you all fields that have sorting on them and if the sorting order is ascending or descending?

Comment: @Hobroker Based on your example, you haven't executed the query (using `run()`) so you have no data to operate on until you do.

Comment: @Dimu Designs you are actually able to return properties of your query prior to executing it. Just figured I would mention it. All you have to do is declare the filter or sorting and you will be able to retrieve its property via a console log.

Comment: @MarkusMalessa That holds true for properties of the query object. But I was referencing the result set, which is what (I assume) the OP was referring to.

Comment: @Dimu Designs I see your point. Unfortunately the OP wasn’t very clear what they are after.

Comment: What do mean "it doesn't work"? try `for(var i in query.sorting){console.info(i)}`

Comment: @TheMaster Just a heads up, `query.sorting` actually has some properties that are hidden and therefore your code would return g, b, c, and a. Doing a console log on `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(query.sorting)` returns [g, b, c, a, 'all model field names'].

Comment: @MarkusMalessa thanks, this helped

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on my interpretation, which is that you would like to return the column name and the sorting order of the column that has sorting, I would propose the below solution.

First, note that when using `query.sorting.YourFieldName.` in your query server script, the following options are presented in the code autocomplete - _ascending, _descending, _order, and _priority. When hovering on the _order choice you will note that this is a read-only property and it states that ascending order will return true and descending order will return false. What is not mentioned is that no order on a particular column will return undefined.

So the following code worked for me and returned a console log with the column name and the order, albeit this code does not pick up if there are any relation fields that are sorted:

```
var query = app.models.Person.newQuery();
query.sorting.Name._ascending();
var fields = app.metadata.models.Person.fields;
for (var i in fields) {
  //if statement first checks column is not a foreign key and that column has sorting 
  if(i.indexOf('_fk') === -1 && query.sorting[i]._order !== undefined) {
    console.log(query.sorting[i]._order ? 'Column Name: ' + i + ', Order: Ascending' : 'Column Name: ' + i + ', Order: Descending');
  }
}
```

The console would return "Column Name: Name, Order: Ascending". Let us know if that is what you are in fact looking for.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want to get the information in one column only and then sort it out. You can use basic javascript for that. Here is an example of what you need:

First you use [array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to get only the information for one column.

```
var query = app.models.Person.newQuery();
var allPersons = query.run().map(function(person){return person.Name;});
```

Now that you have an array containing all the names in the the **Name** column, you can proceed to sort it using [array.sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

```
allPersons.sort();
```

That should give you the list of the Names sorted alphabetically in ascending order.